# I want to use pinia state management in my vue 3 project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I am trying to use pinia state management in vue 3 but I am getting this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/stores/cart' in
> 'C:\Users\Ali Haider\theme-project\src\views\pages

```js
// This is my Products component
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useCartStore } from "src/stores/cart"; // Import your cart store

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Products-",
  setup() {
    const cartStore = useCartStore(); // Use your cart store

    const addToCart = (product) => {
      cartStore.addToCart(product);
    };

    return {
      addToCart,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Below is my Stores/cart.js file in which I have declared `pinia` state and where I am trying to use it in the products. What am I doing wrong? Also how can I use `pinia` with the `laravel` API to fetch data?

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useCartStore = defineStore("cart", {
  state: () => ({
    cart: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    addToCart(product) {
      console.log("product added");
      this.cart.push(product);
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The problem is what it says, you try to import a module from a path where it cannto be found, it doesn't matter if it's Pinia. You say "Stores/cart.js" but it's "stores/cart", wrong casing. And it's unknown if your project is configured to use "src/" for absolute import path.

Comment: No, this is not the issue. I am trying it to import the way it should be I've tried everything but in vain. Kindly, refer this post to someone else that could help me out. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The question doesn't conform SO rules without it, nobody but you knows what your problem is. It's unknown how it was possible for you to import Products component. You can try exactly the same kind of imports on. As I said, "src/" depends on your setup. Try relative paths with dots

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an IDE like IntelliJ, the linter will help you see if the reference is good or not.

As mentioned by [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask), you might try using dots in your path.  My imports usually look like:

```
import { useCartStore } from "./src/stores/cart";
```

Also, if possible, mark the 'src' folder as a source folder in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Change `src/stores/cart` to `@/src/stores/cart`